# Android studio gradle - avoid rebuilding of modules

Tags: android, android-studio

Can I somehow tell android studio to NEVER build my submodules? I split my apps into many modules and reuse modules between my apps. I have like 10+ modules for an app...

So for the sake of speed I want to tell android studio, to only check dependencies of my main project and only build my main project and NEVER check my modules or do anything with them if I do not force it via a clean build.

Is that possible? If I include all moduels via a compiled jar, android studio would act like that. I want the same behaviour even if I don't include the jars but add the modules to my project.

**Question**

Can I only get the desired behaviour if I compile my modules myself and add the jars to my project or can I somehow have the same behaviour with modules as well with the possibility to make changes to my modules from my main project and force recompilation of the modules via a clean build or similar?